# spring-boot-starter-web with web application type NONE. Why?

Tags: spring-boot

I had never used `CommandLineRunner` before, because I've always written web servers. This time I'm building a microservice (CRON job) that wakes up, make some rest and db calls, and stops.

For this project, like others, initially I had the following dependency:

```
implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:$springBootVersion"
```

Until I found out there is something called `CommandLineRunner` and, as I don't need a web server running, I can actually turn it off by `.setWebApplicationType(WebApplicationType.NONE);`

Now I'm wondering what's the point of including `spring-boot-starter-web` if we turn off its web server? I'm using Spring Boot framework to use its dependencies by default (things like jackson, etc.) and for its dependency management framework.

(Side note: I tried to move to `sprint-boot-starter` but there the following issue that I couldn't resolve, so I think I keep using `spring-boot-starter-web` :

`Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder`)

Answer (score 0):

We can see that `spring-boot-starter-web` includes:

```
spring-boot-starter
spring-boot-starter-json
spring-boot-starter-tomcat
spring-web
spring-webmvc
hibernate-validator
```

Looking at where `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` is located we can see that it is in `spring-web` which is included by `spring-boot-starter-json`.

I suspect if you add `spring-boot-starter-json` you will be one step closer to running your service without the web server component.

Maven dependency analyzers can save quite a bit of trouble in the future by starting at the top and looking at what each of the POM files include.